# Differentiation under the integral if and only if we have an $L^1$ dominator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and define
>
> $$g(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} f^2(x)\exp(-tx^2)dx$$
>
> for $t\geq0$. We want to show that $g(t)$ is continuously differentiable if **and only if** $xf(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

If we have that $xf(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then we can use the standard Lebesgue Dominated Convergence technique to show that $g(t)$ is differentiable, and that its derivative is continuous. I'm having trouble, however, showing that $g'(t)$ continuous means that  $xf(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

My attempt: It seems intuitive to me that if $g(t)$ is continuously differentiable, it's derivative must be defined by what we'd expect:

$$g'(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} -x^2f^2(x)\exp(-tx^2)dx,$$

but I don't know how I would go about proving this. If we have this fact, then $g'(0)<\infty\Rightarrow xf(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and we're done.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is $f$ real-valued or complex-valued?

Comment: The necessary and sufficient conditions are provided by the Vitali convergence theorem. You must show that the family of functions $g_h(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)^2 \exp(-tx^2) \frac{\exp(-hx^2)-1}{h} dx$ are uniformly integrable and tight only if $xf \in L^2$. Tightness follows from rather milder assumptions on $f$ (for example, $f \in L^\infty$ is enough), so you probably want to focus on the uniform integrability.

Comment: Sorry, I made an error: you need to show that $g_{h,t}(x) = f(x)^2 \exp(-tx^2) \frac{\exp(-hx^2)-1}{h}$ are, for each $t$, integrable with respect to $x$ uniformly in the parameter $h$ only if $xf \in L^2$. Certainly the "worst case" is $t=0$, as you pointed out, so try to assume that $xf \not \in L^2$ and prove that $g_{h,0}(x)$ is not uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 2):

The "only if" part only holds for real-valued $f$.

For any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, be it real- or complex-valued, we have the continuous differentiability of

$$g(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)^2 \exp (-tx^2)\,dx$$

and the formula

$$g'(t) = \int_\mathbb{R} \left(-x^2\right)f(x)^2\exp (-tx^2)\,dx$$

on $(0,+\infty)$ by the dominated convergence theorem, since

$$x \mapsto x^2 \exp(-tx^2)$$

is uniformly bounded for $t \geqslant t_0 > 0$.

Now, if $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} g'(t)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, then $g$ is differentiable in $0$ and $g'(0) = \lim\limits_{t\to 0} g'(t)$. Then $g$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,+\infty)$. Conversely, if $g$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,+\infty)$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} g'(t)$ exists and equals $g'(0)$.

Now, if $f$ is real-valued, then the integrand of $g'(t)$ is non-positive, and

$$\lim_{t\to 0} g'(t) = \lim_{t\to 0} \int_\mathbb{R} \left(-x^2\right) f(x)^2\exp(-tx^2)\,dx = -\int_\mathbb{R} x^2 f(x)^2\,dx \in [-\infty,0]$$

by the monotone convergence theorem. The limit is finite if and only if $xf(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

If $f$ is complex-valued, then the limit may exist even if $xf(x) \notin L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Consider

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x < 1\\ \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2k-1}} &, 2k-1 \leqslant x < 2k \\ \frac{i}{x\sqrt{2k}} &, 2k \leqslant x < 2k+1,\end{cases}$$

where $k$ runs through the positive integers.

Then $xf(x) \notin L^2(\mathbb{R})$ since the harmonic series diverges, yet $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} g'(t)$ exists (and equals $-\log 2$), since $x^2f(x)^2$ corresponds to the alternating harmonic series. (There's a little work to do to show that the limit indeed exists and equals the improper Riemann integral of $x^2f(x)^2$.)

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the fact that once we know that $g(t)$ is continuously differentiable we can write
$g'(t) = \int_\mathbb{R}(-x^2)f^2(x)\exp(-tx^2)dx$,

but it seems like, as you indicate, we can use monotone convergence here as well, since the integrand of

$g'(t)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\exp(-(t+h)x^2)-\exp(-tx^2)}{h}f^2(x)dx$

is non-positive and increasing. Does this seem correct?

Comment: For $g'(t) = \int (-x^2)f^2(x)\exp(-tx^2)\,dx$, I would, for $t > 0$, strongly recommend the dominated convergence theorem. By the uniform boundedness of $\lvert x^2\exp (-tx^2)\rvert$ on $[t_0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}$, the dominated convergence theorem gives us the continuous differentiability of $g$ and the integral formula for $g'$ on $[t_0,\infty)$ for every $t_0 > 0$, and thus by exhaustion on $(0,\infty)$. The monotone convergence theorem is used to show that $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} g'(t)$ exists if $f$ is real-valued (so $f^2(x)\geqslant 0$) and equals $\int (-x^2)f^2(x)\,dx$.

Comment: That gives, for real-valued $f$, the equivalence of $xf(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and the continuous differentiability of $g$ on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: It seems like both approaches work. There's another similar problem where we have to show that $g(t)=\int_\mathbb{R}\cos(tx)f(x)dx$ with $f(x)\geq 0\in L^1$ is twice continuously differentiable iff $x^2 f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For this problem, it seems like the uniform boundedness approach wouldn't work, whereas we can, on the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ write out the limit definition then apply monotone convergence.